# Java counting connected regions in a grid

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, grid

I am trying to locate all four-connected regions in the grid. A four-connected region consists of a set of marked cells (value 1) such that each cell in the region can be reached by moving up, down, left or right from another marked cell in the region. The assignment states that we should use recursion.

An example input would be:

> 10 20
>
> 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
>
> 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1
>
> 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1
>
> 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
>
> 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
>
> 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0
>
> 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0
>
> 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
>
> 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0

And the output should be:

> > 0  1 1 0 0 0 2 0 3 3 0 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 5 0
> >
> > 0  1 1 1 0 2 2 0 0 3 0 0 4 4 4 0 0 0 5 5
> >
> > 0  0 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 3 0 0 0 4 0 0 0 5 5 5
> >
> > 6  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3 3 0 0 7 0 0 0 5 5 5 0
> >
> > 6  6 0 6 0 0 0 3 3 3 0 0 0 8 8 0 5 5 0 0
> >
> > 6  6 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 9 0 8 8 8 0 0 0 0 0
> >
> > 0  6 6 6 0 0 0 9 9 9 9 0 0 8 8 0 8 0 0 0
> >
> > 0  6 6 6 6 6 0 0 9 9 9 0 0 0 8 8 8 8 8 0
> >
> > 0 0 0 6 6 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0 8 8 0 0 8 8 0
>
> 10 0 6 6 6 6 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 8 0 8 0 0

Right now when I run the code I have, I get this output:

> 0  2  2  0  0  0  2  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  0
>
> 0  2  2  2  0  2  2  0  0  2  0  0  2  2  2  0  0  0  2  2
>
> 0  0  2  0  0  0  2  2  0  2  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  2  2
>
> 2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  2  2  0
>
> 2  2  0  2  0  0  0  2  2  2  0  0  0  2  2  0  2  2  0  0
>
> 2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0
>
> 0  2  2  2  0  0  0  2  2  2  2  0  0  2  2  0  2  0  0  0
>
> 0  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  2  2  2  0  0  0  2  2  2  2  2  0
>
> 0  0  0  2  2  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  2  2  0  0  2  2  0
>
> 2  0  2  2  2  2  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  2  0  2  0  0

My code looks like:

```
package project2;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class project2 {

    private static int height;
    private static int length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputFile;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter input file name: ");
        inputFile = input.nextLine();

        try {
            Integer grid[][] = loadGrid(inputFile);

            System.out.println("Before flood fill");
            printGrid(grid);

            findGroups(grid, 0, 0, 2, height, length);

            System.out.println("After flood fill");
            printGrid(grid);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void findGroups(Integer[][] array, int column, int row,
            int counter, int height, int length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                if (row < 0 || row >= length || column < 0 || column >= height) {
                } else {
                    if (array[i][j] == 1) {
                        array[i][j] = counter;
                        findGroups(array, column, row + 1, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column, row - 1, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column - 1, row, counter, height, length);
                        findGroups(array, column + 1, row, counter, height, length);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Integer[][] loadGrid(String fileName) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream fin;

        fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);

        Scanner input = new Scanner(fin);

        height = input.nextInt();
        length = input.nextInt();

        Integer grid[][] = new Integer[height][length];

        for (int r = 0; r < height; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = input.nextInt();
            }
        }
        fin.close();

        return (grid);
    }

    public static void printGrid(Integer[][] grid) {
        for (Integer[] grid1 : grid) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[0].length; c++) {
                System.out.printf("%3d", grid1[c]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I believe I am moving the counter up after each time. Does anyone have a recommendation of what the issue might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a question more appropriate for Code Review?

Comment: What is code review? I fairly new to the site, sorry.

Comment: Try asking your question here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/